# Assigning to Similarly Named Entity Properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, variable-assignment

This is tenuously related to [C#: How do i assign many variables with an integer(i) in for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777639/c-how-do-i-assign-many-variables-with-an-integeri-in-for-loop).

Basically, I have an entity with properties Category1Results, Category2Results, Category3Results... etc up to Category60Results. There are also around 15 other properties. These map to a database table.

Is there a sensible way to assign to these?

A loop seems like it might be helpful, where (for example) the property with name Entity.Category+i+Result is assigned to, but I'm not sure how one would achieve that.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with reflection.  Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402479/using-reflection-to-set-a-property-of-a-property-of-an-object) post where Jon Skeet provides a solution to assign an objects properties.

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 60; i++)
{
   SetProperty(entity, "Category"+i+"Result", valueYouWantToAssign)
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390594/c-setting-property-values-through-reflection-with-attributes) is another example that loops through the properties of the object.

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(MyClass).GetProperties();
foreach(PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
    property.SetValue(instanceOfMyClass, attribute.DataValue, null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I've gone with the first method, which works well. I would have thought that the latter option is the more elegant, but it requires a bit of tinkering in my code and I'm just looking for a quick fix for now. Thanks again!